# Is there a way to match only the error type during a doctest?

Tags: elixir

So, for example, I have:

```
  @doc ~S"""
  Fails on more than 6 elements:

      iex> values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
      ...> Units.ProjectedValues.new(values)
      ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Units.ProjectedValues.new/1
  """
```

However, I would like to only test that `FunctionClauseError` is raised, not the message content itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't any direct way right now. The [parser](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/fe8f19f6bbeaf1478257638e3f3cee6255a3116d/lib/ex_unit/lib/ex_unit/doc_test.ex#L596-L608) creates an empty string as the message if you don't provide any, and there doesn't seem to be any check to treat an empty message (or any other message like `"..."`) as a match all.

If you need to do this several times in your doctest, and really do not want to write the complete messages, you could use a helper macro like below:

```
defmodule M do
  @doc ~S"""
      iex> M.sum([1, 2, 3])
      6
      iex> M.rescue_struct M.sum({1, 2, 3})
      FunctionClauseError
  """
  def sum([]), do: 0
  def sum([x | xs]), do: x + sum(xs)

  defmacro rescue_struct(expr) do
    quote do
      try do
        unquote(expr)
        raise "expected an error to be raised"
      rescue
        e -> e.__struct__
      end
    end
  end
end
```